# Extracting an NSString from both Parenthesis and Quotations

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsscanner

I have a string that is returned from a WebAPI call that looks like this:

```
    (
    "username@domain.com"
    )
```

As a workaround, I am trying to extract just the email address i.e. username@domain.com

I am not sure what the best approach to do this is as I'm extracting the data within the parenthesis and the quotations.

Any pointers (no pun intended) are appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't by accident the web client return JSON? Like `["email@domain.com"]`?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use [`stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet%3a):

```
NSString *source = /* your source */;
NSCharacterSet *charSet = 
    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \"()\n"];
NSString *email = [source stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charSet];
```

Harder one involves [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks. Tried both the NSMakeRange and stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet and both times I get an error: -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e42c0

Comment: That means that your variable isn't a string, it's an `NSArray`. Try printing to log `[source objectAtIndex:0]`, maybe your parentheses are just part of the array notation, not of a string.

Answer (score 0):

An even easier one, if you know that the string always starts with `("` and ends by `")`:

```
NSString *email = [response substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, [response length] - 4)];
```